# Rust | Как сменить целевую архитектуру компиляции с x64 на x86?

Tags: компиляция, rust

В настройках Cargo и rustc можно выбрать лишь целевую платформу, в моём случае x86_64-pc-windows-msvc. А конкретная разрядность выбирается непонятно каким местом: мне нужно скомпилировать приложение под 32, но компилятор упорно строит 64, что бы я ни делал. Как это побороть?

Comment: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-build-both-32-and-64-bit-app-on-windows/26365/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для 32-разрядного Windows вам может подойти такое название целевой архитектуры:

`i686-pc-windows-msvc`

Компилировать под неё, соответственно, так:

```sh
rustc ... --target i686-pc-windows-msvc
```